# How to manipulate message.content in an @client.command() section without MissingRequiredArgument Error

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I created a ticket command in which a person sends ">ticket" followed by a question. However, when I have ctx and msg in the same function I get the error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: msg is a required argument that is missing.`
and when I switch the orders of ctx and msg in the function the error occurs for ctx.

```py
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx, msg):
    if msg.content.startswith('>ticket'):
        print('ticket was made')
```

I tried the method with the * in between the 2 and that gives me the same error. I also tried putting this if statement in the `on_message` function but that makes it so the command doesn't run when I type in ">ticket" and only does the code in the `on_message` function.

Comment: i use the ctx part of the command later on in that function when sending embeds

Comment: How about just passing ctx to it and getting the message with ctx.message

Comment: so i should have the message as ```ctx.message.startswith(">ticket")``` ?

Comment: you should have `async def ticket(ctx):` you can get the message with `msg = ctx.message` under the command

Comment: i get the following error when I tried that way ```RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rest of the message" will be in the `msg` variable, so you don't have to cut it out. In case you only use it as `>ticket`, there will be no extra parameters passed into the function, so it will be `missing`, as your error suggests.

A way to stop the error from getting raised is to make it `optional` by giving it a default value, and then check if anything was passed or not.

```py
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx, *, msg=None):
    if msg is None:
        print("No arguments were passed!")
    else:
        print(f"The rest of the message is: {msg}")
```

```
>ticket

>>> No arguments were passed!

>ticket something something

>>> The rest of the message is: something something
```

Comment: thank you very much, that fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctx.message`, but the thing is, you're using a command. it's already named `ticket` (you can't invoke it any other way than `>ticket`) and you're checking again if it's the right command? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: I'm checking the starts with so I can strip the command portion later on and keep just the message they sent following the command. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also doesn't make sense, if you want arguments you pass them in the function. I don't think you know how exactly commands work, take a look at the [introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)